# SQL Server 2014 Computed Column Specification Calculated Field Formula Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2014, management-studio-express

Using the below column names in the formula field of computed column specification category (using Management Studio).

```
[[App_1]+[App_2]+[App_3]+[App_4]]
```

I'm getting this error:

> 'MyDatabase' table
>   Error validating the formula for column 'Total'.

`App_1, App_2, App_3, App_4` all are numeric values.

Anyone knows how to handle this?

Comment: The correct formula is `([App_1]+[App_2]+[App_3]+[App_4])`

Comment: Show create table script

Comment: @Jaco, I tried your suggestion also but getting the same error

Comment: @JaydipJ, I created the table using SSMS not using SQL so unable to provide you the script.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Total` column?

Comment: You can obtain the table script from SSMS by right clicking on the table and selecting *Script Table As* > *CREATE To* > *New Query Editior Window* from the menu.

Comment: @Tom Chantler, Total Column Data Type is Int.  App_(1234) are Bit.

Comment: @destination-data, I am a newbie with sql codes so SSMS is the only way I can able to do the changes.

Comment: Seeing the table script will help us figure out why the computed column isn't working for you.  If you could edit your question to include that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of the enclosing square brackets (`'['`, `']'`), use:

```
[App_1]+[App_2]+[App_3]+[App_4]
```

Alternatively you can try with an SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD [new_col] AS ([App_1]+[App_2]+[App_3]+[App_4])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but getting the same error.

Comment: @Sixthsense Which version of Management Studio / SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Sixthsense It executes ok on my end (with the same version)

Comment: @Sixthsense You didn't mention the the fields are of type `bit`. You said `numerical`. Its not the same thing.

Comment: @ Giorgos Betsos, you fixed it.  LOL how silly I am!!! The bit part made the real hassle.  I changed all the fields as int then your suggested syntax worked perfectly. "[App_1]+[App_2]+[App_3]+[App_4]".  Thank you very much!!!